# How do I create an object with a default value if none is passed in the parameter?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm trying to create a table that will default to size 500 if no value is passed to the constructor.

**Example**

```
Table object; //sets table size to 500 by default
Table object(10000); //sets table size to 10000
```

This is how I currently have my header set up:

```
Class Table{
public:
    Table();
    //other functions excluded
private:
    static const int tableSize = 500;
    std::vector<int> A[tableSize];
};
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `Table(int size = 500);` to set a default value in the constructor, thus making the parameter optional.

Comment: @Biffen Doing that gives me errors for this line `std::vector<int> A[tableSize];`

Comment: "Errors", eh? *What* errors? And what is that line supposed to achieve? It looks a bit strange.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely what you're looking for, assuming you wanted a *table* and not just a sequence. You code made no mention of the size of each *row* in that table, so I'm going with what you had:

```
class Table
{
public:
    Table(size_t n = tableSize) : A(n) {};

    //other functions excluded
private:
    static const size_t tableSize = 500;
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > A;
};
```

If that size of your row buffers is **fixed** (say 100 columns), you could use a `std::array<>` for your row buffers, and thus this instead:

```
class Table
{
public:
    Table(size_t n = tableSize) : A(n) {};

    //other functions excluded
private:
    static const size_t tableSize = 500;
    std::vector< std::array<int,100> > A;
};
```

---

**EDIT**: Growing Your Hash Table

it appears from comment this is to provide a hash table implementation, and in so doing the need to expand the hash table is required (probably one reason for this in the first place). In that, you can expand the original directly by doing this in conjunction with the first snippet:

```
void Table::expand()
{
    size_t new_size = 2*A.size() + 1;
    std::vector< std::vector<int>> tmp(new_size);
    for (auto& x : A)
    {
        std::hash<int> hfn;
        for (auto y : x)
            tmp[hfn(y) % new_size].push_back(y);
    }
    std::swap(A,tmp);
}
```

or something similar. Your hash function would obviously need proper integration as well as potentially taking an optional size factor, etc, but you can hopefully get the idea.

Comment: I want it to be a hash table.

`std::vector<int> d[tableSize];`

Array size 500 by default with a vector in each array for pushing data.

Comment: Change vector to unordered_map and you will get a hash table. There is a ton of info out there about this. But your original question is well-answered by @WhozCraig and Biffenn.

Comment: @Lanyard If you're doing this yourself (the hash table) then go with the first snippet. And use A.size() anytime you need the current object's hash table size. That said, I would strongly encourage what @Steger said and just use an `unordered_map`. It really is the cat's whiskers.

Comment: @WhozCraig I am doing this for a class assignment. I thought I was finished until I noticed that the constructor must have an optional parameter. If nothing is passed, then it creates an array size 100 with each index containing a vector size 0. If 600 is passed, then it creates an array size 600 with each index containing a vector size 0;

Comment: Yeah, I somewhat figured. Hash tables are usually done with vectors of linked lists, but to each their own. The first sample should do what you want. The outer vector of vectors should size to the default if you don't specify one, but I think you would be better off implementing a simple expansion function and just grow the table as the load factor is surpassed (rehashing all elements and reslotting them in the process, don't forget to do that).

Comment: @WhozCraig It's all working now. I switched from an array of vectors to a vector of vectors. I do have a working version that uses linked lists but those confuse me. I stopped 80% of the way through and switched to a vector of vectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```
Class Table{
public:
    Table(int size = 500): A(size) { }
private:
    std::vector<int> A;
};
```

(note that it's shown this way for brevity.  You could/should separate the interface from its implementation and define `Table::Table` in a source file, and the initializer list should go with it.)

Comment: How can I modify this to support an array of vectors?